# How to create efficient function in C for handling multiple arguments to be formatted in char array

Tags: c

Lets say I wanted to construct a string with many different values from a struct in C to build a SQL query.

**The python way to handle string formatting could be:**

```
str = "INSERT INTO main.post VALUES('{0}', '{1}');".format('title', 'Some random text here...')

print(str)
```

Result after print(str):

```
INSERT INTO main.post VALUES('title', 'Some random text here...');
```

**Current code:**

I'm using a typedef for defining my structure. Then initializing it with these values:

```
typedef struct {
  char              title[50];
  char              text[5000];
} post_t;

post_t post = {
     {
         "title",
         "Some random text here..."
     }
};
```

Is there some clever way I can do this in C? I will have a lot of different SQL queries so it might be good to create some sort of util function for handling it.

Comment: Or better to use `snprintf()` to help protect against buffer overrun.

Comment: what if the title is `','');DELETE FROM main.post;--` ?

Comment: Something like `printf("INSERT INTO main.post VALUES('%s', '%s');", post.title, post.text);`?. Replace `printf` with `sprintf` or `snprintf` as needed. Read the documentation of the functions mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `snprintf()` to do that:

```
post_t post = {"Title", "Some random text here..."};
char query[1024];
snprintf(query, sizeof(query), "INSERT INTO main.post VALUES('%s', '%s');", post.title, post.text);
    
printf("%s\n", query);
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO main.post VALUES('Title', 'Some random text here...');
```

But as @[user253751](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106104/user253751) pointed out, this code is very prone to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You will have to use [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to prevent that.

Here are some C APIs for some database providers:

- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/c-api-function-reference.html)
- [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnoci/database-access-c-api.html#GUID-322BCDA4-1A70-4BD1-85F1-FAACC4C772F5)
- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html)